# Liberty server properties file setup

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have properties file in local to which I am reading in code by below method
String pathOfFile = System.getProperties("arg.get.prop");

How to set this system properties to get my property file's path in liberty server.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to define system property the recommended way is to use `jvm.options` file and put your property there like:

```
# Set a system property.
-Darg.get.prop=ExampleValue
```

you may need to create that file in the `${server.config.dir}` directory. For some more details check [Customizing the Liberty environment](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html)

Comment: According to you if my key value pair is name.stack.flow=solution   .Then I will write in jvm.option as  Dname.stack.flow=solution .RIGHT

Answer (score 2):

You can specify environment variables in the server.env file placed either in ${wlp.install.dir}/etc/server.env or ${server.config.dir}/server.env.  The server will also pick up variables from the current shell environment (server.env files take precedence).  Then you can access the variables in the server.xml using the following notation:

```
${env.<variable name>}
```

For example, you can have the following in your server.env file:

```
HTTP_PORT=9001
```

and then in your server.xml:

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="${env.HTTP_PORT}"
              httpsPort="9443" />
```

For more information on customizing the Liberty environment see: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html

Answer (score 0):

if your property file is in "variable=value" format .. then, you can include in in bootstrap.properties file of your liberty install.

bootstrap.properties can be used to supply variable values to liberty configuration. you can include additional files by specifying 
bootstrap.include=

Comment: the downside of bootstrap.properties is that they get set after JVM starts up, so isn't good for system properties the JVM reads. This is only really good for JVM options an application reads.